# Is this JSON or something else?

Tags: javascript, php, json, graph, devexpress

I want to get some values from a sql database for a graph via php. I want to give the javascript graph the values via JSON but the weird thing is, the valuesneed to look like this:

```
{
    Player: 3,
    Game: 'Diablo 3'
}, {
    Player: 1,
    Game: 'Overwatch'
}
```

I am not sure...but is this some sort of JSON? because when I echo a json_encoded array with php it looks like this:

```
["3","1"]
```

when the first is no JSON is it something own and how could I format the values in the best way that they fit for the graphs?

Comment: not a JSON. This is JavaScript Object Literal notation

Answer (score 0):

This might be [hjson](https://hjson.org).

> Hjson is a syntax extension to JSON. It's NOT a proposal to replace JSON or to incorporate it into the JSON spec itself. It's intended to be used like a user interface for humans, to read and edit before passing the JSON data to the machine.

Also, it may be a valid JavaScript object, except the parent array ‘[]’ notation is missing.